# NopCommerce strip plugin source code

Tags: visual-studio, stripe-payments, nopcommerce

Does anyone have or know where I can get the Stripe plugin source code for NopCommerce 3.40?

The plugin here is compiled for deployment. http://www.nopcommerce.com/p/1512/stripe-payment-plugin.aspx

Id like to be able to access the controllers because there fields in their view "Login id" and "transaction id" in the configure.cshtml and I think it should be "secret key" and "Production key" for Stripe.

Answer (score 1):

You have to contact the author of this plugin. Or you can manually decompile it in order to see it source code

Comment: These are good Idea's.  I will be looking into both.   As far as a manual decompile,  is their a tool for this?  or is it more like I just look at whatever I have and then start guessing what the controllers and models should look like?